# Android - 9patch padding on a Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I created a button with a 9patch image as a background. In the 9patch image I used the bottom and right lines to specify the content area/padding, to position the text on the button. This works well on a TextView, but on a Button the content lines seem to have no effect on the text position. Setting "paddingTop"/"paddingBottom" also seem to have no effect - only "padding" has any effect.

This is my layout XML:

```
<Button 
            android:layout_width="450dp"
            android:layout_height="198dp"
            android:text="Some text here"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/my_button"/>
```

Is there any way to set the padding? Maybe I could use a different View instead of a Button? For example, I could try to just use a TextView and make it clickable, but I'm not sure what other side-effects this will have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly setting `android:padding="@null"` solved my issue.

The issue seemed to be that a Button (or one of the styles in the theme I'm using) is setting the padding, which overrides all other padding in the button - padding in the background drawable, as well as `paddingTop`, `paddingLeft` etc.

My button layout is now defined like this:

```
<Button 
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="198dp"
        android:text="Some text here"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"/>
```

My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 11.1) picked up the `@null` as an error, even though it compiled. Setting it to `-1px` also worked.

Comment: Tangentially related, sometimes using "early access" IDEA versions solve those parsing errors: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP

Comment: I filed a bug report - it seems like it will be fixed in 11.2

Answer (score 1):

If you use a 9-patch image as background, both the padding and the stretched areas are defined in the background.

It's quite graphic if you use the draw9patch tool: the padding is defined (indirectly) with the content area (lines on right and bottom):
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: In the 9-patch tool it shows the content area exactly as I want it, and is it is when used on a TextView. However, when used as the background of a Button the content area seem to be ignored.