# wrap_content is not working in button height android

Tags: android

"wrap_content" is not working in my button, it currently looks like this:

```
 now                        want
 ____________
|            |           _____________
|   aaaaaa   |     =>   | aaaaaaaaaaa |
|____________|           -------------
```

and the xml for my buttons :

```
 <Button 
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:id="@+id/input_expend"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"                               
     android:textSize="12sp"
     android:text="aaaaaaa"                         
     android:background="@drawable/btn_01"/>
 <Button 
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:id="@+id/input_expend"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"                               
     android:textSize="12sp"
     android:text="aaaaaaa"                         
     android:background="@drawable/btn_02"/>
```

How can I solve this problem?
  Thanks!

Comment: maybe your drawable adds extra padding!

Comment: On a different note, your `android:id=` is same for both the buttons ?

Answer (score 58):

`Button` is a `View` and the `android:minHeight` attribute is set `48dip` default. You can set `minHeight` lower than your actual text 'aaaaa' such as 1dp. Then `wrap_content` will work. But I don't think this is recommended.

Comment: It is absolutely not recommended. 
A button has a minHeight and minWidth to make it easier for the user to touch it and don't miss it. It should also have always a margin, so the user don't click a button by it's side. Read the Material Design Guidelines. https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-style

Comment: You should also try btn.setMinHeight(0), or btn.setMinimumHeight(0), or both.

Comment: Can you point to the Android Documentation for Button minHeight, minWidth?

Comment: It worked for me. I think set `minHeight` or `minWidth` lower than default value little is fine. I set both value to 40dp and 80dp.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add `android:padding="@null"` to the button in your XML. This will override any existing padding being enforced.

There is also an issue I've come across where a button will not shrink smaller than the padding defined in the default button style. I highlighted this in [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803009/get-programmatically-created-button-to-correctly-implement-padding-from-9patch) some time ago
but haven't had an answer that resolves it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the background didn't work, as well as padding="@null".

I ended up using a TextView because my button was simple enough for it to suffice:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Join"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/xsmall_text_size"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_selector"
        android:background="@color/turquoise"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap_content will not shrink a button smaller than the background.  If you are already using a nine patch for the background, then cut back the size of the regions to the smallest they can be.  If there's not a gradient, then you only really need about two pixels to define the stretchable regions and then make sure the central area is as small as it can be.   Use the padding (right and bottom lines on ninepatch) to allocate the padding.

If you're using a drawable image (not a nine-patch or xml drawable) then make it a nine patch drawable

If you don't want to solve the problem in the image, you will need to set the layout_height to a fixed value to force the image to shrink (ie don't use wrap_content)

Answer (score 0):

The background is adding unwanted padding

Answer (score 0):

Adding just minHeight doesn't work.
You also need to set verticalPadding to 0dp

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingVertical="0dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Login"/>
```