# Relative layout rendering incorrect (buttons are messed up)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Expected layout :
[image]

Layout rendered : 
[image]

Layout xml source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_back"
        />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/back"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_background"
        />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/midban"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_mid"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_right"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/share"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_fb"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dummyright"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fb"
            android:background="@drawable/layoutslices_new_10"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fb"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dummyright"
            android:background="@drawable/layoutslices_new_09"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buy"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dummyright"
            android:background="@drawable/layoutslices_new_11"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imdb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rt"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dummyright"
            android:background="@drawable/layoutslices_new_12"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The correct aspect ratio is being maintained for all of the layout but the the buttons marked trouble are messed up as shown in the picture.

Could anyone tell me where am I missing the layout element or I believe I am missing some basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. You have to use ImageView instead of Buttons. Hope this helps someone. Biggest waste of time.

You cannot go below a certain height for a button even if you use wrap content and setbackground image. It scales the image up to the default height if the height of the image is below the default value. I am not sure if this is a bug or this is the expected behavior.

You can also refer here: [wrap_content is not working in button height android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386572/wrap-content-is-not-working-in-button-height-android)