# How to get android studio Component(Button, text,etc...) size (Width, height or default size)

Tags: android, button, layout, intellij-idea

I am developing android studio plugin using `intellij` and I want to get Component size(button or textview's width,height ) in `intellij` plugin.

[image]

In the picture, I wrote the code `height="wrap_content"` and width as `"wrap_content"`.

I want know that button size( dp or px number).

Also when `textview` or another component are defined `wrap_content`, I don't know width and height.

I think, android studio components has default width and height. But I don't know where it is defined!

Thank you!

Comment: I think you are making an app.

Comment: i made app but now i develop android studio plugin, so i want to know component default size

Answer (score 0):

The default size for `android:minHeight` attribute is set `48dip` by default.

**And take a look:** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

> ***WRAP_CONTENT***, means that the view wants to be just big enough to
>   enclose its content (plus padding)

And of course: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23984754/4409113

Comment: 48dp is default height and width to the component?

Comment: I think that is only true for those components who has `android:minHeight` attribute.so, i think yes.but you may want to try it with getHeigh() and getWidth and then use it for your porpuse.

Comment: now i check button default size, default width is 88dp, default height is 48dp... and text view default width is 27dp, height is 16dp...(just defined text...)
i don't know default defined!

Comment: Yeah, good, but, that could be due to that device size i guess.by the way, i couldn't find anything about this default size except that `minHeight`

Comment: ok... so where you find minHeight default size?  code? or web surffing?

Answer (score 0):

To get `Button`'s **Width** and **Height** use this code.(Use this code in `onCreate` Method)

```
Button customButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.customButton);
customButton.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
      Log.e("Button", "Width = "customButton.getWidth() + " Height = " + customButton.getHeight());
      }
});
```

`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` returns `Button`'s **Width** and **Height** in `px`.

Comment: thank yoy but this code is android studio in app....
i want to know component default size just project file, so i use this information by intellij plugin